# White screen when browsing around

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby's built-in Link component for all internal links around the site but for some links it keeps pushing the user to a completely white screen.

If you take a look here https://5f0ce4c9e45bb4001142106c--novos-beta.netlify.app/

then click on the top nav links you can see that it takes you to a white screen, clicking back then brings you back to another white screen.

When you hit the white screen pages a number of console errors appear. These are not visible in development mode which is making it tricky to work out what the issue is.

Any pointers on what this might be?

Comment: Is there an available or source code to check?

Answer (score 0):

could you check how you have names the files inside pages folder? The names you have used have alot of dashes in them. For example your blog is called seo-ecommerce-blog. I reccomend changing it to blog and then link it to blog in the Link and seeing if that works